# lstat returns -1

Tags: c, stat

I use `lstat` to take a file`s characteristics, but it doesn't appear to work, it returns -1 and the error -No such file or directory-.

I try the path in the shell, typing :

```
:~$ ls /home/mypc/Desktop/file.c
/home/mypc/Desktop/file.c
```

So this path obviously works with `ls`, but not with `lstat` ! It is very weird.
This is the line in which I call `lstat`:

```
int i=lstat(path, &buff );
```

`path` is a `char[]` and `buff` is a `struct stat` object.

Please if you have any ideas...

Comment: Probably, your `path` is wrong. Let us see how do you set it.

Comment: `printf("%s\n",path) ;` before you stat it to see what `path` is set to.

Comment: You can also use `strace`, `ktrace`, `ktruss` or `truss` (whichever is available on your platform) to see what exactly happens.

Comment: I do it with fgets,that is right.the problem is that i don t know a perfect way to put the path I get from fgets in a char foo[],and then in lstat. I tried to do it even with getcwd but it wont work.can someone write an example with getcwd ,with the path given by fgets and with lstat? thnx

Answer (score 4):

This is correct behavior. Your path doesn't exist.

From the documentation:

**RETURN VALUES**
     Upon successful completion a value of 0 is returned.  Otherwise, a value
     of -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.

As @Noufal states, you can try printing the path. It may be that your path has a `\n` appended to it; this is likely if you read it with `fgets`.

Comment: I do it with fgets,that is right.the problem is that i don t know a perfect way to put the path I get from fgets in a char foo[],and then in lstat. I tried to do it even with getcwd but it wont work.can someone write an example with getcwd ,with the path given by fgets and with lstat? thnx

Answer (score 1):

From fgets manual page: `If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.`

So you are trying to lstat `/path/yourfile.c\n`. Obviously you file name is `yourfile.c` and not `yourfile.c\n`.

**more explanations added**

Your "path file" is something like `/path/to/yourfile.c\n/other/path/to/otherfile.txt\n`. The file "uses" `\n` (new line) characters to separate the different entries in the file.

When you read it using `fgets`, the `path` variable is filled, each time, with a full line read from the "path file" including the ending `\n` character. So if you look inside your program memory, you'll discover that `path` looks like `/path/to/yourfile.c\n\0somegarbage` (after the first call to fgets).

Now, you have to get rid of the trailing `\n`, just before the `\0` that identifies the end of the string.
As you wrote in one of the comments,you can use `memset` to do this but, IMHO, there are easier ways.

Comment: so how do I delete the \0 ? with memset for example? : memset(&path[last_element], 0, sizeof(char)); is this right?

Comment: No, do not delete the '\0'. You have to delete the '\n' before the '\0'. Ok, I'll edit the answer

Comment: there is a \n before the \0 ??? first time I hear this. So, if I have a string, what do i have to do to it to pass it in lstat? if you can please give an example as you said.thanx !

Comment: Thanx!Thanx!Thanx!Thanx! i did it.it was so simple. thank you;)

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of `fgets`:

fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
       stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading  stops  after  an
       EOF  or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
       A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the  last  character  in
       the buffer[...].

So this is your situation.

`path\n\0
 ^^^^ ^ ^
 1234 5 6`

Remmber this! Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, look at the error value. The path may exist, but be otherwise reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
It is right that I use fgets to read a line from a pipe that gives me the paths.
The problem is not that the files is unreacheable for sure,because I checked this.
the problem is the path itself.I do:

```
while ( (fgets ( path, 512, f ) )) {//path name is f.e.: ./.local/share/Trash/files/myFile.c
       struct stat buff;
       //here I have the path and I give it in lstat
       if(lstat(&path[1], &buff )==0){ //I give path[1] and not path[0] to avoid the dot in the begining
       }
}
```

the error must be the pathname.

Comment: You'd not create an answer to add new details. Instead you can edit the question. In any case, please, format the code using the [markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).